# What c# ribbon elements allow keytips on a drop down?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbonx

I am building a VSTO add-in for Excel using C# and an XML ribbon.

I cannot get keytips to work on buttons once I put them in a drop down.

I have tried various elements for the drop down, including the following dropDown, Gallery, & Menu.

The keytips work when the buttons are just in a group, but once I move them inside one of these elements they no longer work.

I have seen this functional on an add-in before at my previous employer (PwC), but now am trying to code a similar add-in myself at a new firm.

An example of the behavior I want is like any of the native menus, e.g. Accessing Home > Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules via alt+H+L+H.

What I am failing to get is for the menu/drop-down item, "Highlight Cell Rules" in the example, to still have a keytip once placed into the dropDown/gallery/menu.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

Turns out, none of them can, but there is a workaround.

None of them can:

- Keytips themselves are only for items present on the ribbon itself.
- You cannot have an actual keytip on a button (or other item) that is, e.g., in a menu that is on the ribbon.
- This was my original issue.

Workaround:

- There is a workaround, which is what Excel itself uses in combinations noted in the original question such as "alt+H+L+H".
- Note how the keytip in the menu item (Highlight Cells) is underlined and is present in the label, but the keytip of the menu in the ribbon itself (Conditional Formatting) is not.

Implementation:

- The way to implement this in the xml ribbon code is as follows.
- In the example, I make a ribbon called "JBM" with a drop-down menu called "Number Formats" with a button called percentage, which can be accessed via the keytip combination "Alt+X+N+P", even though the percentage button itself is not on the ribbon.
- (Note: All items inside of a ribbon element must be in a group element first, but these elements don't use keytips either and are more just like boxes.)

```
    <ribbon id="JBMRibbon" label="JBM" keytip="X">
      <group id="formatsGroup" label="Formats">
        <menu id="numberFormatsMenu" label="Number Formats" ketyip="N">
          <button id="percentageFormatButton" label="&#38;Percentage" />
        </menu>
      </group>
    </ribbon>
```

Summary: Place `&#38;` in the label text itself before the letter that you wish to function as a keytip.

I am not sure what this is called or how it works, but it works.  I found the solution at this link:
https://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons:Keytips_in_Ribbon_Controls

Thank you if you looked into this, and I hope this helps others in the future.